# How to find the google page rank of a website in php?

Tags: php

How to find the google page rank of a website in php?

Comment: What do you mean by the “page rank of a website”? The PageRank value of a certain page or the rank of the first occurrence of a website within the results of a certain query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I googled and found a few classes:

- http://www.pagerankcode.com/download-script.html
- http://www.fusionswift.com/examples/2011/10/google-pagerank-api-in-php-october-2011/
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2682-PHP-Retrieve-the-Google-page-rank-of-a-given-URL.html

Quickly looking, I think the second one is your best bet (it uses the Google Toolbar API). Just make sure your server supports CURL

Comment: but you knw if we are using google tool bar to get PR its a spam by google.

Answer (score 2):

There's a PHP script at http://www.brightyoursite.com/blog/2010/06/01/use-php-to-get-google-page-rank/ which works pretty well for this. It makes requests to the Toolbar API.

Usage is pretty simple:

```
include "pr.php";
$url='http://www.example.com';
echo "$url  PR is ". getPagerank($url) ;
```